# HTML content in XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't know is it possible. I have an XML file, which in tags have HTML tags, but in the next style:

```
&lt;p&gt;
```

is it possible, with help of an XSL transformation, to show this information in normal HTML. For example if I get `&lt;img src=""%gt` I see the image?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031139/how-to-decode-a-html-string-using-xslt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the tag

> xsl:value-of

add this

> disable-output-escaping="yes"

Result:

```
<xsl:value-of select"/something" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_value-of.asp) you have more info!